# Delete from SQL with PHP Statement still occurs even with non-existant ID

Tags: php, mysql, recaptcha

I can successfully delete URLs from my SQL table by using their unique ID. However if i were to enter an ID which does not exist, it still says "Deletion was successful". I don't think its an error with the recaptcha.

For example, when i enter the ID '201', an ID which is yet to exist in the database, it still says "Deletion was successful". What is the way to solve this?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete_btn']))
{
        $googleurl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $privatekey = "Intentionally not shown :')";

        $response = file_get_contents($googleurl."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $data = json_decode($response);

    if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true)
    {   
    $query = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM phishurls where id=?");
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $query->bind_param("i", $id);
    if ($query->execute()){  //execute query
      echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("URL has been deleted!")</script>'; //if deletion from database is successful
    }else{
      echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error in deletion ")</script>'; //if deletion from database is unsuccessful
    }
    }
    else{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Please complete the recaptcha!")</script>';
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: use `mysqli_affected_rows` - if it is zero then do not display success message

Comment: Check the effected rowcount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `mysqli_affected_rows` ~ Returns the number of rows affected by the
>   last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.

You can use the value returned by `mysqli_affected_rows` to perform a logic test and proceed accordingly

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['delete_btn'] ) ){
        $googleurl = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $privatekey = "Intentionally not shown :')";

        $response = file_get_contents($googleurl."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $data = json_decode($response);

        if( isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true ){   
            $query = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM phishurls where id=?");
            $id = $_POST["id"];
            $query->bind_param("i", $id);

            $result = $query->execute();
            $affected = $con->affected_rows;


            if ( $result && $affected==1 ){  //execute query
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("URL has been deleted!")</script>'; //if deletion from database is successful
            }else{
                echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error in deletion ")</script>'; //if deletion from database is unsuccessful
            }
        }
        else{ 
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Please complete the recaptcha!")</script>';
        }
    }
?>
```